# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error on below code.

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Code:

```
private void RefreshListType(bool forExport)
{
    grdListItems.DataSource = ListType.GetListTypes(Convert.ToInt16(cboListType.SelectedValue));
    grdListItems.DataBind();
    lblCount.InnerText = "LookUps: " + grdListItems.Rows.Count.ToString();
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: does cboListType.SelectedValue actually have a integer value in it? eg not "" or "abc"

Comment: What have you tried? For instance, have you isolated the parts in that code that *could* produce that error?

Comment: That suggests `cboListType.SelectedValue` couldn't be parsed as a short. As you haven't told us what that value is, it's hard to help you more than that...

Comment: Which line does your exception appear?

Answer (score 2):

Likely `cboListType.SelectedValue` is not able to be made into an `int16`.

You can use `int16.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

SelectedValue doesn't return a number?

You could put a TryParse in before to check that the selected item has a numeric value.

```
Int16 nValue = -1;
if (Int16.TryParse(cboListType.SelectedValue, out nValue))
{
    // Proceed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you are getting from `cboListType.SelectedValue` is not convertible to Int16.

Right-click on the page and select "View Source" and then hit Control-F to search for 
"cboListType" look at the value that is selected.

You can also use `Response.Write` or a javascript alert to write the value.

Answer (score 0):

This, most likely, means that `cboListType.SelectedValue` is not a valid number